# Firebase Admin SDK - Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() ... failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I initialized the SDK Admin in my code, but when I call an admin function it complains about credentials and tokens. Any idea what this could be caused by?

```
var serviceAccount = require('../../../path to the actual json file);
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://<name of my database>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

### Output

```
Error fetching user data: Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: incorrect header check. Error code: Z_DATA_ERROR".
        at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (error.js?8304:42)
        at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (error.js?8304:88)
        at new FirebaseAppError (error.js?8304:122)
        at eval (firebase-app.js?0db4:121)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Z_DATA_ERROR` suggests that gzip is at fault. Make sure the Firebase Admin SDK has been updated to the latest version.

Also ensure that your computer clock is synchronized.

- [How to Synchronize the Clock in Windows 10 with Internet or Atomic Time](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/synchronize-clock-windows-10-with-internet-atomic-time/)
- [How to Synchronize Time with NTP in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/synchronize-time-with-ntp-in-linux/)

And finally, check that the Firebase service account and the database URL are for the same project.

Comment: Hello Sir, i tried syncing the time using the instructions, and I still get these errors. Is it about the chosen location/region of the app when i created it in the firebase console?

Comment: it works using Mirosoft Edge Browser, but not in Chrome, Firefox

Comment: @EricAlmendral See updated note about Z_DATA_ERROR.

Comment: hello sir,  I use the firebase admin sdk with vuejs.  is it possible that the cause of the problem is because Im using the sdk on the client?

Comment: @EricAlmendral Using the Admin SDK on the client could be causing the problem. **The Admin SDK should only be used in a secure environment and not exposed to clients.**

Comment: Thank you @ChristopherPeisert, ill try to wrap it in the cloud functions :)